Merge columns with same name but one empty and another containing values
I have a dataframe in which there are couple of columns with same name. How can I merge them in the same dataframe?
df:
items_group quantity    items_group quantity
                           KIT1240  12
KIT1265      7      
KIT1265      6      
KIT1198A     6      
                           KIT1264  12

expected output:
items_group quantity
KIT1240      12
KIT1265      7      
KIT1265      6      
KIT1198A     6  
KIT1264      12 


Assuming there exists only one valid set of values per row, stack with dropna=True, then unstack:
df.stack(dropna=True).unstack()

# or
df.stack().dropna().unstack()

NB. I'm specifying an explicit dropna since a future version a stack won't drop the NaNs by default.
Alternatively, using groupby, but this will be deprecated in the future:
df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).first()

Output:
  items_group quantity
0     KIT1240     12.0
1     KIT1265      7.0
2     KIT1265      6.0
3    KIT1198A      6.0
4     KIT1264     12.0

Used input:
df = pd.DataFrame([[None, None, 'KIT1240', 12],
                   ['KIT1265', '7', None, None],
                   ['KIT1265', '6', None, None],
                   ['KIT1198A', '6', None, None],
                   [None, None, 'KIT1264', 12]],
                 columns=['items_group', 'quantity',
                          'items_group', 'quantity'])

